# What framework is best for a 2D top-down shooter in Java?

Tags: java, framework, game-development

I'm creating a roguelike shooter in Java where the bullets are projectiles (not hitscan), the camera moves with player movement, so that the player character is always in the middle, and where I'm always showing just a small part of the entire playarea (like a 12x20 section of a 60x120 map). I want the camera movement to be smooth as well.

Out of JavaFX and libGDX which is more apt for this usecase and which is easier to get into? If you know a similar open-source idea I'd love to either in action. My application is only for Windows PC and isn't a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

Even it should be a 2D game, [Java 3D](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/java-3d.html) could be helpful. Also you could try a gameengine like [jMonkeyEngine](https://jmonkeyengine.org/).